# How to move content of a folder to current folder?

Tags: cp, mv

I have this folder structure:

```
foo
`----> bar
```

How can I extract the content of `bar` into `foo`?

I tried `mv -f bar/* .` from within `foo`.

> -f, --force  | dont't ask before overwrite

but I get "could not move `bar/ajax` to `foo/ajax` because the directory is not empty"

How can I solve this?

Comment: `mv` complains for reasons, in the end it depends what exactly you want to happen when there are folders and files to be overwritten... There are also some corner cases to take note of, e.g. what happens when there is a `bar/bar/`, or other conflicts.

Comment: Is there anything else in foo? (is it just bar?)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, there are many other files and folders in foo

Comment: It is best to edit the question, so that people see it (not just leave amendments in the comments).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`mv` will overwrite files, but it will refuse to overwrite *directories*. There's no single command that will merge directories and remove the source directories (which is probably what you want with `mv`). Even `rsync --remove-source-files` will leave empty directories.

You can use a combination of commands:

```
cp -a dev/. .
rm -r dev
```

which copies everything in `dev` to the current directory and then removes the `dev` directory.

Or:

```
rsync -a --remove-source-files dev/ .
find dev -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

which uses `rsync` to move all the files, and then deletes the empty directories left behind.

Comment: this is copy, not move.

Comment: @OfusJK This is copy+delete,  which is what "move" is in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue at Hand

You wish to move the contents of `foo/bar/` up a level to `foo/`.

I will be referencing [this post on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory) as well as [this post from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/231983/move-files-from-subfolder-to-current-folder) in the solution.

## Solution

[According to user Stephan202](https://superuser.com/questions/62141/how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory), you are looking for the following commands to execute this task:

```
cd /path/to/foo/bar
mv * .[^.]* ..
```

It should also be possible, from within `foo/bar/`, to run the following command as well:

```
(shopt -s dotglob; mv -- * ..)
```

Verify you have the correct permissions as well. If needed run the command with root(sudo) privileges.

## Conclusion

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I revised this answer to indicate the pros and cons.

Some manual pages are rather terse because the information is mentioned in the corresponding Info manual.

> #### Man
>
> **-f, --force**
>
> do not prompt before overwriting
>
> #### Info
>
> **Note:** `mv` will only replace *empty directories* in the destination. Conflicting populated directories are skipped with a diagnostic.
>
> [...]
>
> **-f,**
> **--force**
>
> If a destination file exists *but is normally unwritable*, standard input is a terminal, and the `-f` or `--force` option is not given, `mv` prompts the user for whether to replace the file. (You might own the file, or have write permission on its directory.) If the response is not affirmative, the file is skipped.

`mv` cannot replace non-empty directories but can overwrite existing files owned by the user which are normally unwritable (the owner do not have write permissions, c.f. the quotation).

```
foo    
|-- ajax
`-- bar
    `-- ajax
```

You can merge the directories `foo/ajax` and `foo/bar/ajax` either keeping all files or overwritting identical files as proposed by [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453587/286944).

However, this method is unsuitable if the contents of these directories are unrelated. It may be not obvious at first glance so let's see a new tree.

```
prompt% tree home/network
home/network/
├── data
│   ├── img
│   │   └── demo.png
│   └── src
│       ├── contact.pdf
│       └── report.pdf
├── hardware
│   ├── api
│   ├── docs
│   └── src
│       └── driver.c
├── misc
│   └── src
│       └── init.py
├── README
└── src
    ├── main.c
    └── manager.c
```

We can move the contents of `network/data` into `network` and choose to merge directories having the same name (c.f. below).

```
prompt% cp -ab home/network/data/* home/network
prompt% rm -r home/network/data/*
prompt% tree home/network
home/network/
├── data
├── hardware
│   ├── api
│   ├── docs
│   └── src
│       └── driver.c
├── img
│   └── demo.png
├── misc
│   └── src
│       └── init.py
├── README
└── src
    ├── contact.pdf
    ├── main.c
    ├── manager.c
    └── report.pdf
```

As we can see, the final directory `network/src` may contain unrelated files after moving. If it is undesirable, we can rename files and directories having the same names after moving.

```
prompt% mv -b -S "_data" home/network/data/* home/network
prompt% tree home/network
home/network/
|-- README
|-- data
|-- hardware
|   |-- api
|   |-- docs
|   `-- src
|       `-- driver.c
|-- lib
|   `-- demo.png
|-- misc
|   `-- src
|       `-- init.py
|-- src
|   |-- contact.pdf
|   `-- report.pdf
`-- src_data
    |-- main.c
    `-- manager.c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory `foo` **that only contains** a directory `bar`. (`bar` may contain other stuff).

And you want to rename `foo/bar` → `foo`, then do:

```
mv -T foo foo.original
mv -T foo.original/bar foo
rmdir foo.original
```

You can leave of the `-T` if your `mv` does not have this option, however it makes it safer.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use the move command :

```
cd foo
mv bar/* .
```

As Jeff Schaller suggest, use

```
 shopt -s dotglob
```

before the mv command to move hidden files and use the option `-i` of mv if you want an interactive check before overwriting

Comment: In bash, consider setting dotglob so that this picks up “hidden” files.

Comment: Note that this may overwrite files that have the same names in both folders, and that hidden files are skipped.

Comment: Does not work, I get `Not possible because the directory is not empty"